# java xml literal constructor

Tags: java, xml

Looking for a minimalistic creation of test xml objects, I've following.

```
DocumentBuilder doc = (DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()).newDocumentBuilder();
doc.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader("<msg txt='HelloWorld'/>")));
```

Is there a least verbose option to create an XML in java?

**Preferably a one liner native java solution without requiring a 3rd party pom dependency.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with a JDOM parser.Try

```
<dependency>
<groupId>jdom</groupId>
<artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
<version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>





import org.jdom.Document;
import org.jdom.Element;

Element xyz= new Element("xyz");        
Document doc = new Document(xyz);
doc.setRootElement(xyz);
Element test= new Element("test");      
staff.setAttribute(new Attribute("msg txt", "HelloWorld"))
```

Refer any tutorial.https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_jdom_parse_document.htm

Comment: the given answer is verbose, is there a single liner solution?

Comment: Other than this there are options like dom4j,stAX,xpath but all of them are 2-3 lines code as above

Comment: so basically xml support in java is poor, are your other solutions based on native java without requiring need for 3rd party pom components?